# Something is wrong with my ul

Tags: html, html-lists

Trying to make a very simple html page. For some reason the <ul> seems to jump out of the <div> and go on top, meaning the <ul> becomes the first thing on the page.

Here is my code  http://jsfiddle.net/pnQCs/2/

Comment: I applaud you for including a jsFiddle. Can you include a screenshot so that we know exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: In the code you will see the <ul> is after the <table> finishes, why does it display before everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the first `table` tag, before the `tabWrapper` div.

```
</table> <!-- add this -->
<div id="tabWrapper">
```

What are all those blind tables doing there anyway? Just style your divs.